# Gui freeezing when using threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, freeze

I am stuck and was hoping someone could help me.

I have made a class/gui with a loading bar set to marquee so that when a task is being carried out i could display it to the user.

In one of my gui classes, in the constructor on the first line i am making a new instance of this class and then doing

```
    LoadingBar bar = new LoadingBar();
    Thread thread = new Thread(bar.Show);
    thread.Start();
```

However, even tho the main programme thread is going off doing some more intensive stuff, this gui still seems to freeze, even if i use backround worker.

Is there anything wrong with the approach i have mentioned and if so what do i need to change?

Thanks

Comment: WinForms application? What is LoadingBar control?

Comment: it is a windows form application, and loadingbar is a class i made with a progressbar in it and a label saying loading!

Comment: Put the UI code in the main thread. Put anything else in worker threads.

Comment: See my example for the code and steps required to run this via a background worker

Comment: It doesn't work because the thread you started isn't pumping a message loop.  Which makes the window catatonic.  Application.Run or Form.ShowDialog is required.  But absolutely, this really should be done the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reverse your method. The GUI needs to stay in the main thread while the work is done in a "worker thread" (typically a BackGroundWorker). Then the worker reports back to the GUI which then updates.

Comment: Additionally he have to use Control.Invoke if he will continue use Thread

Comment: Yeah, BackGroundWorker is a lot better suited really. With nice events and all.

Comment: Yeah, He shouldn't continue to use Thread, BackgroundWorker is painfully easy and I gave a quick overview of the process

Answer (score 2):

You'd better do the opposite.  Make your intensive work in the thread (or a background worker), and show the wait screen in the main application thread.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `BackgroundWorker`.  Drag one onto your form, click `backgroundWorker1` and set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property to `True`

Then goto the events (via the properties window) and attach handlers for

- `DoWork`, this is where all the work that is represented by the progress bar.  You will "report progress" via this and the background worker will make sure ProgressChanged is called on the UI thread.
- `ProgressChanged`, this is where you update the UI based on progress and state data reported to the method

`DoWork` event looks something like this

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var userState = new StateClass();

    while (working)
    {
        // TODO: do work here

        // update the state surrounding this task via userState
        userState.property = "some status";

        // report the progress so that backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged gets called 
        this.backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentComplete, userState);
    }

}
```

`ProgressChanged` event looks like this

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.UserState contains the state data you passed to ReportProgress, 
    //   you have to cast it to the right type though, since its of type object
    var userState = (StateClass)e.UserState;
    int progress = e.ProgressPercentage;

    // TODO: report progress to the UI with the above variables
}
```

Now all you have to do is tell the background worker to do work by calling 
`this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing all your work within the background worker or the GUI wouldn't be freezing. We'll need to see more of your code or you'll need to have another look at background worker examples to see what could be wrong.

EDIT

Add a call to `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);` after your report progress call