# How to error handle overclicking in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, button, error-handling, clicking

i have a program. If i over click a button, the whole program freezes. i don't know the code to error handle this. does anyone know how to error handle this.

thanks

Comment: Show your work.. People can't read your mind.

Comment: Don't overclick the button, or show a In progress message to the user.

Comment: I feel like a simple boolean flag can avoid the poor performance.

Comment: You can probably add a Thread.sleep when you handle the button click +  make the button unable to be clicked for that time. This is bad design though.. but if all else fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Trapping C# and Over Clicking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586166/error-trapping-c-sharp-and-over-clicking)

Comment: It is sound like threading problem please post your code and put more description for the problem. Keep in mind if you run any long process in the button in the same thread will freeze the UI you need to run it in own thread I will post for you an answer.

Comment: Need more, (some:), code...

Answer (score 3):

Put your button clicked code in another thread see this examples:

[Gui freeezing when using threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194725/gui-freeezing-when-using-threading)